# Can not call API from backend mongodb

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb

I'm trying to call my mongoDB API but it's giving me this error:

> xhr.js:178 GET http://localhost:3000/api/products 404 (Not Found)

Here is how I call my API:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchItems = async () => {
      setLoading(true);
      const res = await axios.get("/api/products");
      setProducts(res.data);
      setLoading(false);
      console.log(res.data)
    };
    document.title = `Shop - The Beuter`;
    fetchItems();
  }, [props]);
```

And here is my server.js:

```
const express = require("express"),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
    app = express(),
    cors = require("cors"),
    port = process.env.PORT || 8000,
    db = "beuter",
    path = require("path"),
    server = app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening to on port ${port}`));

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
    app.use(express.static('beuter/build'))

    app.get('*', (req, res) => {
        res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'beuter', 'build', 'index.html'));
    })
}
require("./server/config/database.config")(db);
require("./server/routes/product.route")(app);
```

this is my database.config.js:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

module.exports = (name) => {
    mongoose
        .connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI || `mongodb://localhost/${name}`, {
            useNewUrlParser: true,
            useUnifiedTopology: true,
            useFindAndModify: false
        })
        .then(() => console.log(`Successfully connected to ${name}`))
        .catch((err) => console.log(err));
};
```

How can I fix this problem?

Here is my github project if you want to look over my code:
https://github.com/nathannewyen/the-beuter

Comment: are u getting the error only when `NODE_ENV` is set to `production` ??

Comment: Probably unrelated but using both express.json() and bodyparser.json() is wrong because they do the same thing.

Comment: @Panther after i get rid of NODE ENV it's still give me that error

Comment: @Panther seems like i cant change react app from port 3000 to 8000

Comment: @Panther check if any other service is running on port 3000, if there exist, then change your server's port number.

Comment: My backend is running localhost:8000 and react-app running port 3000 but when I tried to put those 2 in the same port It gave me this `? Something is already running on port 8000. Probably:
  /usr/local/bin/node server.js (pid 93498)
  in /Users/nhannguyen/Desktop/the-beuter

Would you like to run the app on another port instead? ` @HimanshuBhardwaj

Comment: If your backend is running on port 8000 why are you fetching data from 3000?

Comment: @Panther you cannot run more than one service on a single port at same time